# Turbolinks-Android <input type ="date" /> not working as expected with min sdk version 19

Tags: android, turbolinks, turbolinks-5, turbolinks-android

I've started a Turbolinks android application and have a form that requires a date input.

```
<form>
  Birthday:
  <input type="date" name="bday">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

The problem is that when I touch on the date input field it doesn't present the native android date picker which is odd because when I load the page inside the Chrome browser on the device it does..

I know that android WebViews only support these kind of HTML5 inputs from API version 19 onwards, so I've setup my application as such:

**app/build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapp.turbolinks.app"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            postprocessing {
                removeUnusedCode false
                removeUnusedResources false
                obfuscate false
                optimizeCode false
                proguardFile 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    compile 'com.basecamp:turbolinks:1.0.7'
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}
```

I'm not using any CSS or JS libraries that could interfere either.
I've also checked that emulator uses the Chrome web view implementation.
I've tested it with `type="datetime"` and `type="time"` which don't work either.

I'd appreciated any help on this. Maybe I've missed something?

Thanks.

Comment: Turbolinks is the cause. They instantiate with Application Context which means these dialogs won't work.  From WebView documentation ```Note: WebView should always be instantiated with an Activity Context. If instantiated with an Application Context, WebView will be unable to provide several features, such as JavaScript dialogs and autofill.```

Comment: Hi! Did you manage to figure it out?